# How can I disable Windows XP shutdown while still allowing log out/restart?

Tags: windows-xp, shutdown, gpedit

I want to disable the "shut down" option on a Windows XP machine whose case and power button is not easily accessible. Users must still be able to restart and logout, but not shut down.

Is this possible?

Edited to add: I prefer any solution not using `gpedit.exe`, otherwise we would need to create a separate policy for this single machine.

Comment: It's not that hard to create per-machine policies.  You can keep them in a separate folder named something like "Individual fixes".  You can also edit the policy for a machine at the machine itself, as long it's not enforced to a particular state by the domain.

Comment: Now there did this downvote come from? Please leave a comment explaining what's wrong with this topic -- thanks!

Comment: that was to leave you with exactly 9,000 points, so you should be grateful for such awesomeness for this great base 10 rounded number! :D

Comment: @Cawas Now I am OVER 9000! Success! (my apologies to the two users getting notified about this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to gpedit you can edit manually the reg-key which would be modified by gpedit:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

create a new DWORD value named NoClose and set its value = 1

Reboot the pc and the 'shutdown' button should be disappeared.

NOTE: shutdown command from prompt will work

Comment: To disable it for all users also edit this reg key
HKEY_LOCAL_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer.

Shutdown from task manager will also work after these edits.

Comment: Worked like a charm. This is effectively the same setting as the better-known gpedit solution, so it might not work with more restrictive policies in effect.

Comment: In my case this tip will remove also the restart button. How is that?