# Can the shutdown button be hidden in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I have a production system (Windows XP) that must be shut down via a special script. It must not be shut down/restarted using the shutdown button.

How can I hide the shutdown button, so nobody can accidentally do the wrong procedure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable Windows XP shutdown while still allowing log out/restart?](http://superuser.com/questions/173439/how-can-i-disable-windows-xp-shutdown-while-still-allowing-log-out-restart) and/or [How to completely disable windows shutdown or restart in XP](http://superuser.com/questions/298888/how-to-completely-disable-windows-shutdown-or-restart-in-xp?rq=1)

Comment: Why can't you just use Group Policy Editor to assign a shutdown script? Then it will be applied automatically on shutdown.